# Cannot access File Server from one workstation but can from another with same credential

Tags: networking

I have Small Business  network with one file server and 25 workstations in workgroup. Lately I've been experiencing some difficulties. Latest: one of the user cannot sign in into network share on the file server from one computer but can do it from another.The message is :Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. I setup same profile with credentials and one is OK but not another. All workstations have Windows 7 64 bit and our file server is Windows Server 2008 R2. I tried few things suggested on this site but it didn't work.
Thank you

Comment: First guess: the time on the workstation and the server is more than 15 minutes apart. If that isn't it, can you check the server's security event log for the error which appears when the login fails, and edit your question to include that message?

Comment: Yea, that I checked and it is not an issue,  i also looked into events log on a server. And it didn't go through due to authentication issue. I tried 3 different workstations with same result, but forth one still connects. I triple checked user name and passwords - they are identical

Comment: Interesting. What about the workstation regional, language and keyboard settings? Are there any characters in the passwords which might be different on different keyboard maps, e.g. # or $ or [, etc.?